# List is accepting only one comment

Tags: python, list, web, web-scraping, instagram

I was passing customizable comments for Instagram. I was writing the following Code:

```
def comment(username,comment) :
    driver.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{username}/")
    time.sleep(5)

    for i in range(7):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")

    href_found = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    pic_href = [ele.get_attribute('href') for ele in href_found if '.com/p' in ele.get_attribute('href')]

    #comment = ["Nice Work"]

    for ele in pic_href:
        driver.get(ele)
        time.sleep(3)


        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")

        commentbox = lambda: driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea")
        commentbox().click()
        commentbox().clear()


        for i in comment:
            commentbox().send_keys(i)
            time.sleep(random.randint(1,7)/30)

        commentbox().send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    login("<id>","<password>")
    desire_user = input("Enter Instagram Username to Comment: ")
    comm = [x for x in input("Enter comments").split(",")]
    for i in comm:
        comment(desire_user,i)
```

The idea is to create a list of comments and enter one comment per post. For example:
passing the first comment for the first post and then next comment for the next post and so on.

Can anyone please help me with the following script.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing i instead of comm in your method comment.

```
for i in comm:
    # comment(desire_user,comm)
    comment(desire_user, i)
```

Comment: Thank you Sankalp Bose for your help but It is still printing only one comment... Please confirm if you can help with that

Comment: Actually I was wrong, usage of comm was correct. You should refactor your code as such,

create the list of comments comm;
create the list of posts pic_href;

zip the two lists created above using zip(comm, pic_href) This creates a new list with tuples (comment, post);
create a function which takes a tuple (comment, post) and adds comment to post